# Water pressure is very unstable

Tags: plumbing, water-pressure

I'm having some very weird issues with the water pressure in my house.

- When nothing is running, the pressure reads 110 PSI. Obviously I want this to be lower.
- When the toilet is flushed, the pressure crawls to 10PSI. Same thing happens when the bathtub is on. At this point, sinks quit working.
- When only a sink is on, it goes to 100PSI.
- No matter what, when all the water turns off, it jumps back to 110PSI.

Why is this happening? Is it normal for a pressure reducing valve to read a very high pressure when nothing is running?

Comment: Pressure and flow rate are two different things, but related to each other.  1) where do you get your water? Is it city service or your own pump/well?  2) is this a new problem? Or has it always been this way?

Comment: @Tyson City water. I don't think our pressure has always been at 110 psi but I only noticed recently. I think it has been this way for a few years at least, everyone remarks at how high it is. So I tried adjusting the pressure reducing valve and that's when these weird problems of going to 10PSI started occurring. I'm probably going to replace the valve

Comment: You might be adjusting the pressure reducing valve in the wrong direction.   Typically I find them to operate in reverse of my expectation.  Did you check instructions like [these](http://media.wattswater.com/1910259.pdf) or just start playing with it?   Pressure at rest and running are also two different things.   How old is the valve?  They do need replacement sometimes, especially when inlet pressure is very high.

Comment: @Tyson I saw instructions like those and adjusted it counterclockwise like it says. I had someone upstairs watching the guage as I turned it, but the needle would not move (even after running some water to get a new reading). Stayed at 110PSI. But now things like flushing the toilet cause it to drop significantly. The valve is as old as the house, about 33 years. Thanks for your help!